# No any output display after lazy loading

Tags: angular

I used lazy loading for my project. after that i can not get the expected output by the system.There are no any error in the console. I can't see any wrong thing in this code. then what should i do.

I stopped terminal and restart the project by `npm start` comand. but nothing happen.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'invoice',
    loadChildren :'./invoice-builder/invoice-builder.module#InvoiceBuilderModule',

  },
  { 
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'invoice',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**invoice-builder-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { InvoiceBuilderComponent } from './invoice-builder.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: InvoiceBuilderComponent 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class InvoiceBuilderRoutingModule { }
```

**invoice-builder.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { InvoiceBuilderRoutingModule } from './invoice-builder-routing.module';
import { InvoiceBuilderComponent } from './invoice-builder.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [InvoiceBuilderComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    InvoiceBuilderRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class InvoiceBuilderModule { }
```

**invoice-builder.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-invoice-builder',
  template: `
    <p>
      invoice-builder works!
    </p>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class InvoiceBuilderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

expected output is

```
invoice-builder works!
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from './shared/material.module';
import { InvoiceBuilderModule } from './invoice-builder/invoice-builder.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The browser is show as follow
[image]

The Network Tab shows as follow
[image]

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**invoice-builder.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-invoice-builder',
  template: `
    <p>
      invoice-builder works!
    </p>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class InvoiceBuilderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I assume you forgot to import AppRoutingModule into AppModule

Comment: Can you add code from app module?

Comment: AppRoutngModule is in there

Comment: can you add it to question?

Comment: I feel that everything is ok. what is the error?

Comment: do you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: Yes thats the problem that it looks ok to me too

Comment: There is no any error. That is the amazing reason

Comment: So if you open in browser is it blank?

Comment: So then what should i do. Is there any specific library or component need to lazy loading.

Comment: Yes. browser is blank.

Comment: I added the image of browser. This error has been coming  since the start of theproject.

Comment: Can you also share network tab?

Comment: Could you also post the template code showing your `<router-outlet>`?

Comment: I added the network tab as well as the app.component.html.

Comment: Can you reproduce this is a stackblitz

Comment: The problem is I not added this code for the Github . Is there any method to share this code to stackbiltz by without github

Comment: I put together a stackblitz with your code and it seems to work fin for me.  @Senal did the same.  You could try deleting `node_modules` folder and doing an `npm install` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks good to me, I have made a stackblitz for you. And also in the app.component.html you should have the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Check out the working stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-cqvf1k?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I had added the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in **app.component.html** . you can see it in the question. i can't understand how this code works in the stackblits and not working my localhost

Comment: Can you see `<app-invoice-builder></app-invoice-builder>` tag when you inspect your html body?

Comment: How inspect the html body?. are you remarked about the browser.

Comment: `ctrl + shift + i` or right click and inspect. Yes try to check what you have in your empty web page.

Comment: Yes I had tried once. you can see the result in the question.

Comment: I don't see it in the question, I meant the **Elements** tab on developer console, there you can see the html elements of your web page

Comment: Ok sir, I will  add the result for the question.

Comment: There was very small problem. once i restart the project. That's error solved.